# Anylogic recursive function

Tags: recursion, anylogic

I wanted to input a series of data from an excel file i.e. after providing an input, it is processed and the next data is called upon to be processed and so on.
To do so, I created a variable, assigned it a value, and changed it's value via a function, with respect to the data in the excel sheet.This variable, is going to be the input, which is going to be processed.

Now,if i am to provide the input, the function needs to be called recursively, to provide a new value every time it's going to be called.

I called the function at the input field.Would this lead to the function being called again after the already inputted data has been processed ? If not, how could i recursively call the function to provide a different input after an input has been processed ?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why don't you just loop through your input data row by row and for each row, call your function with the current row data?

Comment: So basically, add in a loop at the input field itself ?

Comment: no, a loop as below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
for (int=0;i<numberOfRowsFound;i++) {
    myFunctionDoingStuffForEachDataRow(myDatatable.get(i));
}
```

This depends on where the data sits but this is the simple approach I would try first. I don't see why you'd need a recursive function, but maybe you can clarify.

Comment: Would this allow the model to run on multiple inputs (i.e. the different row data) and provide a distinct output for each data inputted ? I tried to implement a similar method before, but the model ran with the first data inputted and stopped. It did not consider further inputs.The whole reason that led me to a conclusion of calling the function once again after the model ran once.

Comment: again, please be more specific. Can you explain exactly what data (sets?) you have and how you plan to execute AnyLogic (which experiment type, which data to load when...). What is your exact goal?

Comment: It worked this time.The problem was with the logic of another function. Thank you and sorry for the trouble.